# Extjs Model for nested JSON structure

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-touch

Consider the following JSON structure

```
{
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Ed",
        "orders": [
            {
                "id": 50,
                "total": 100,
                "order_items": [
                    {
                        "id": 20,
                        "price": 40,
                        "quantity": 2,
                        "product": {
                            "id": 1000,
                            "name": "MacBook Pro"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 21,
                        "price": 20,
                        "quantity": 3,
                        "product": {
                            "id": 1001,
                            "name": "iPhone"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here are my models

```
Ext.define("User", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'id', 'name'
    ],

    hasMany: {model: 'Order', name: 'orders', associationKey: 'orders'}
});

Ext.define("Order", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'id', 'total'
    ],

    hasMany  : {model: 'OrderItem', name: 'orderItems', associationKey: 'order_items'}
});

Ext.define("OrderItem", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'id', 'price', 'quantity'
    ],
    hasOne : {
        model: 'Product', 
        name: 'product', 
        associationKey: 'product'
    }
});

Ext.define("Product", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'id', 'name'
    ]
});
```

When I load the data in my store and then check the store record I see this

[image]

I do not get the Orders and stuff inside it. There must be something wrong with the way I have defined the models but I cant seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

**Update**
Here is my store and how I am loading the data

```
Ext.define('Company.store.TestOrders', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.testorders',
    model: 'User',
    data:[
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Ed",
        "orders": [
            {
                "id": 50,
                "total": 100,
                "order_items": [
                    {
                        "id": 20,
                        "price": 40,
                        "quantity": 2,
                        "product": {
                            "id": 1000,
                            "name": "MacBook Pro"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 21,
                        "price": 20,
                        "quantity": 3,
                        "product": {
                            "id": 1001,
                            "name": "iPhone"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }],
    storeId: 'TestOrders',
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory'
    }
});
```

Then later I am looking at the data by using

```
Ext.getStores('TestOrders').getAt(0);
```

Comment: hello

Can you provide store and item you are attaching it to?

where is no problem with your code. it is working, you can check it on this fiddle
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2qqj

Comment: @LightNight Thanks for replying. I have updated my question to include the store and how I am loading the data.

Comment: @LightNight, I see the difference between your approach and mine. Can you tell me why your store model is set to "Product" instead of "User". I thought we were supposed to assign the root Model to the store in cases like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe are you looking for method to get orders and order items from User store?

You can get orders collection from user record using method `record.orders()`.
The same for order item in order collection record : `order_record.order_items()`.

Check this [example on fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2qqv)

Comment: You are right. This gives me what I was looking for.